# Rails: extra field in many to many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

There's something wrong I did with my schema, but I don't understand what exactly and how to make it work like I want to:

- A flight has many seats
- A seat can be used in many flights
- For every combination of flight and seat there's a booking
- One booking can have many flight/seat combinations
- I should be able to see flight.seats.first.booking

Here're parts of schema.rb:

```
create_table "seats", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "airplane_id"
  t.string "row"
  t.integer "column"
end

create_table "flights", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "route_id"
  t.integer "airplane_id"
end

create_table "flights_seats", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "flight_id"
  t.integer "seat_id"
  t.integer "booking_id"
end
```

The booking class has nothing interesting

Comment: What exactly is not working? Is the title of your question "extra field in many to many" from an error message? If so, what code triggered that error message? If that code was `flight.seats.first.booking`, then what does `flight.seats.first` return?

Comment: `flight.seats.first` returns a `Seat`. `flight.seats.booking` returns `uninitialized constant Seat::Booking`

Comment: And what does `flight.seats.first.booking` return? Does it throw an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think maybe the solution is to make Booking a bit more interesting :)

flights_seats with three object ids is a bit of a red flag.

How about this:

```
Booking
  belongs_to :flight # flight_id column
  has_many :tickets

Ticket
  belongs_to :booking # booking_id column
  belongs_to :seat # seat_id column

# remove flights_seats
```

I don't know all your needs but I think that will get you in the right direction.